# Erros with AVCaptureSession to UIImage in Swift 3

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

Here's my setup:

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

do {
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    captureSession.addInput(input)
} catch {
    print("can't access camera")
    return
}

let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer delegate", attributes: .concurrent))

captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
captureSession.startRunning()

let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(CMSampleBuffer)
let cameraImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!)


let comicEffect = CIFilter(name: "CIComicEffect")

comicEffect!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: comicEffect!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!)

DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    let image_view = UIImageView(image: filteredImage)
    self.view = image_view
}
```

I'm getting two errors. The first error is with setSampleBufferDelegate():

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate!'
```

The second error is with CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer():

```
Cannot convert value of type '(CMSampleBuffer).Type' (aka 'CMSampleBuffer.Type') to expected argument type 'CMSampleBuffer'
```

Dose anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first error:

Implement `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` delegate which will give you `AVCaptureOutput` and `CMSampleBuffer` for current session.

`class YourClass : AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {}`

`public func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!){        print("DidDropSampleBuffer")
//use this CMSampleBuffer to get Image
}`

For second error ,
replace this :

`let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(CMSampleBuffer)`

With :

```
`func ciimageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer : CMSampleBuffer) -> CIImage
  { 
    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    let cameraImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
    return cameraImage
  }`
```

this will give you `CIImage`.